# Difference between a Group Process and Parent Process

Tags: linux, process

Hello fellow terminalists,

I was wondering what the difference between a Group Process and Parent Process is? Based on what I know, a Parent process may have several child processes, and a Group Process is just another term used for a Parent Process, since a Parent Process may have many process as a child, "grouping" all child process under one common Group Process. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parent process is a label that would be like your single-mom (or dad, or guardian).

A group process is a label that refers to you and your brother(s)/sister(s).  Or your single-mom's brother(s) and sister(s).  Or your kid's brother(s) and sister(s).

-- I couldn't resist.

Comment: Haha, thanks Egbert. So PID's that have the same PPID would all belong to the same Group Process correct?

Comment: Yes.  PID's that have the same PPID would all belong to the same Group Process.

Comment: Funny indeed, but could you please elaborate?